# How to save image in different file settings in python?

Tags: python

I want to save the image in different file settings with python.

[image]

I make a function `save_image_as()`

```
import bpy

def save_image_as(image: bpy.types.Image, path: str=bpy.app.tempdir, name: str='Untitled', copy: bool=True, file_format: str='PNG', color: str='RGBA', color_depth: str='8', compression: int=15):
    image.file_format = file_format.lower()
    image.filepath_raw = f'{path}{name}.{image.file_format.lower()}'
    image.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply this settings by using the scene and save the image with these options by using image.save_render(...)

There are different properties to set for different file_formats.

```
import bpy
import os

def save_image_as(image: bpy.types.Image, path: str=bpy.app.tempdir, name: str='Untitled', file_format: str='PNG', color: str='RGBA', color_depth: str='8', compression: int=15):
    scene = bpy.data.scenes.new("Temp")
    
    show_name = image.name
    image.name = name
    
    # use docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ImageFormatSettings.html for more properties
    settings = scene.render.image_settings
    settings.file_format = file_format  # Options: 'BMP', 'IRIS', 'PNG', 'JPEG', 'JPEG2000', 'TARGA', 'TARGA_RAW', 'CINEON', 'DPX', 'OPEN_EXR_MULTILAYER', 'OPEN_EXR', 'HDR', 'TIFF', 'WEBP'
    settings.color_mode = color  # Options: 'BW', 'RGB', 'RGBA' (depends on file_format)
    settings.color_depth = color_depth  # Options: '8', '10', '12', '16', '32' (depends on file_format)
    settings.compression = compression  # Range: 0 - 100
    
    # save images with above settings
    if not os.path.isfile(path)
        path = os.path.join(path, name)
    image.save_render(path, scene)
    
    bpy.data.scenes.remove(scene)
    image.name = show_name
    
save_image_as(bpy.data.images['Untitled'], "S:\Temp")
```

You can use [template_image_settings](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=template_image_settings#bpy.types.UILayout.template_image_settings) to expose the image settings to the user.
For example, in the draw method of an Operator:

```
def draw(self, context):
    scene = bpy.data.scenes["My_Scene"]
    image_settings = scene.render.image_settings
    self.layout.template_image_settings(image_settings, color_management=False)
```

This template is exactly the same as your image.

Comment: How to save a copy?

Comment: Why don’t you use the python file copy command?

Comment: This saving process is more like copying the image because it doesn't change anything about the image in Blender.

Comment: I don't want to link the image with external path

Comment: ok, so the Image should stay inside Blender, but these are for exporting an Image as file

Comment: Yes, just to save the copy