# Image Save UI Template

Tags: scripting, interface

I want to add this UI template to my panel which can be found in the window when you are saving an image.

[image]

The closest I could get is this using the "[template_image_settings](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.template_image_settings)". But the color space part is completely different here. But in the [answer to this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274637/how-to-save-image-in-different-file-settings-in-python/275102#275102) is told otherwise. Did something change in Blender so that's why it is different now? The post is only a little over 1 year old.

```
layout.template_image_settings(context.scene.render.image_settings, color_management=True)
```

[image]

Comment: The template you are using is for textures (input) you need the render settings or image save settings (output)

Comment: Which image is the 'input'? The first is from Image > Save As, and the other is from Properties > Output Properties > Output. Isn't both output? Just the first one is simple image save and the second is rendered image save?

Comment: The upper screenshot contains the settings of an image texture node in a material. Therefore color space is not the type you save as (filmic, etc) but the way it is interpreted by the node tree (non-color etc.) I have not looked at the templates, but you can probably edit the code manually, for example color_management=True, see if there are more optional parameters in the template.

Comment: So it doesn't matter what color space I chose on the first image, it won't affect the exported/saved image, right? Unfortunately the "color_management" is the only listed parameter. Also, there is a "Save As Render" checkbox, if I set it to True, the "Color Space" switches to "Color Management" (basically the second image).